# Wordpress Super Admin

Tags: user-roles

I'm trying to block any admin of a Wordpress install from being able to modify certain pages, the sort of stuff detailed here: http://wackao.com/be-a-wordpress-super-administrator/ . Is this even possible? Thank you.

I would like to do this by modifying the core word press files.

Comment: Downvote for "*I would like to do this by modifying the core word press files.*" Unless you intend to maintain a *forked* application, **modifying core files is strongly discouraged**.

Comment: Seconded - WordPress is designed so you should never need to modify core files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend creating a **Custom User Role**, using the [`add_role()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role) function, such as a "*Site Admin*" or "*Sub-Admin*" (or whatever you want to call it). Then, you can [*assign specific user capabilities*](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) to that custom role, thereby giving users exactly the capabilities you *want* them to have, without giving them the capabilities you *don't want* them to have.

For example:

```
<?php
add_role( 
    // Role slug
    'sub-admin', 
    // Role display name
    'Sub-Admin', 
    // Capabilities
    array(
        activate_plugins,
        add_users,
        create_users,
        delete_others_posts,
        delete_pages,
        delete_plugins,
        delete_posts,
        delete_private_pages,
        delete_private_posts,
        delete_published_pages,
        delete_published_posts,
        delete_users,
        edit_dashboard,
        edit_files,
        edit_others_posts,
        edit_pages,
        edit_posts,
        edit_private_pages,
        edit_private_posts,
        edit_published_pages,
        edit_published_posts,
        edit_theme_options,
        export,
        import,
        list_users,
        manage_categories,
        manage_links,
        manage_options,
        moderate_comments,
        publish_pages,
        publish_posts,
        read_private_pages,
        read_private_posts,
        read,
        remove_users,
        switch_themes,
        unfiltered_upload,
        upload_files
    ) 
);
?>
```

(Those are the default "administrator" capabilities, with caps related to editing others' pages, and promoting users, removed.)

## Available Plugins

There are several Plugins available that provide a UI for creating and modifying user roles, including:

- [Members Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/)
- [Role Scoper Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/)
- [User Role Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-role-editor/)

Comment: In addition to the plugins Chip pointed out, check out [User Role Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-role-editor/) - this is the plugin I currently use for role management, and it's done very well for me.

Comment: Thanks for that, super helpful and hard to find info.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, anything is possible with the use of the internet combined with precise and thought-out questions. Here's a plug-in that might help: http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/user-permissions/

Comment: Ok, but if the admin can disable it, it's basically no good, that's why I was thinking of modifying WP core files

Comment: And that is why you should modify your question :)

Comment: Maybe consider granter more permission to a lower level, instead of taking the admin down a notch.