# How To Remove The "Delete" Theme Option In Dashboard

Tags: themes

How do I remove the option to "delete" a theme in the admin dashboard?  I built a site for clients with several themes they can choose from and i don't want them to accidentally delete a theme.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the [`delete_themes` capability](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#delete_themes) from those users.

The easiest way would be to [create a custom user role, based on the "Administrator" role, but omitting relevant caps](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48422/wordpress-super-admin/48433), such as `delete_themes`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few plugins to remove [delete_themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#delete_themes) capability from users.

- [Members](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/)
- [Role Scoper](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/)
- [User Role Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-role-editor/) - My personal favorite